# constructors calling subclass

Tags: c++, subclass, superclass, object-slicing

I have a (partally implemented) class hierarchy where

```
template<typename T> {
    class data { 
        data ( string s ) {}; // loads from file
        ...
    }
    class image: public data <T> { 
        image ( string s ) {}; // loads from file
        ...
    }
    class jpgimage : public image<T> {
        jpgimage ( string s ) {}; // loads from file 
        ...
    }
    // other image types
}
```

Now in the rest of my code I would like to be able to abstract from whether something is a jpeg image or even an image, so I would like to work with `data`. But at the same time I would like to pass commands specific to jpeg images to those functions.

So if I call `data<int> img("lena.jpg");` which turns out to be an image, even a jpeg image, I would like the data constructor to call the image constructor, which in turn calls the jpgimage constructor.

There is no way I can get it to work, and people warn about slicing, virtual constructors, etc. But is this such a strange way to set it up?

Comment: this is not C++. You must make each class a `template`

Comment: What you want is a `Data Factory`. You pass the factory the name of the file. It works out which type of object to create and returns it.

Comment: Chapter 8 of [Modern C++ Design](http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315) by Alexandrescu discusses the Factory pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance is to be used for *is a* relationships. So, an `image<T>` *is a* `data<T>`, but not the other way around! It makes no sense to call a method specific to `image<T>` for a `data<T>` object, which after all may not be an `image<T>`. The fact that you want to do that shows that your code design is flawed. Rethink your code design.

Comment: Point taken. I wanted to code it so that for example, I can load `image<int> im1("lena.jpg");` and `image<int> im2("lena.png");` (with a different constructor, for PNG images) and then use them as objects of the same class. So a jpeg image *is* an image and a png image *is* an image, but I want to only use the fact that they're both images after loading them. In this case, coding the different I/O options as methods rather than different classes is then better, including the filetype-specific parts such as headers etc. -- that was what I thought different classes would be best for.

Comment: I know exactly where you were coming from. But best to think about this for yourself!

Answer (score 1):

To implement that you would need data to be owner of implementation, not base class:

```
template<typename T> 
class base_data {
    base_data ( string s ) {} // loads from file
    // ...  
};

template<typename T> 
class image: public base_data <T> { 
    image ( string s ) {} // loads from file
    ... 
};

template<typename T> 
class jpgimage : public image<T> {
    jpgimage ( string s ) {} // loads from file 
    // ...
    // other image types
};

template<typename T> 
class data {
    data ( string s ) {
        if(is_jpeg( s )) impl = new jpeg_data<T>( s );
        // ...
    } // loads from file
    // ...
    private:
        base_data<T> *impl;
};
```

Now in constructor you can create proper type of implementation and so on.

Comment: Thanks for this. The fact that this requires another class already shows that it is not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a bad design. You don't need to work with generic `data` classes just to *guess* whether you work with images, if you know for sure that you do. Use the `image` or `jpgimage` class where you need it, and make everything else work with a generic `data` class.

Comment: I made the code more concise, because ideally I want something that works with different forms of numerical data, could be images, surfaces, signals, etc. I think the `image` and `jpgimage` class should really be methods of data only.